# Create TCP connection and send data to external server in Apex (like fsockopen and fputs in php)

Tags: apex, webservices

I am trying to establish a TCP connection with a server to send commands to it for use with a web API, as you would with fsockopen and fputs in php. Does anyone have any experience with this kind of thing who can guide me through what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apex itself doesn't provide any mechanism for sockets. The best we have are the [Http/HttpRequest/HttpResponse classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http.htm), which you can use to interact with REST and SOAP APIs provided by third parties outside of Salesforce. You'd need to set up a remote site setting or a named credential as well.

If your service provides a WSDL (web service definition language) file, there is also the option to [generate Apex class(es) from WSDL](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.code_wsdl_to_package.htm&type=5). That approach usually requires a bit of tweaking, as the WSDL parser Salesforce uses has trouble with a few of the possible types that can be used in WSDL.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com is the place to go to learn the basics of Salesforce features you're unfamiliar with. The official [Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dev_guide.htm) is another good resource.